# Bootstrap 4 progress bar not working inside popover (looks like popover limits CSS properties)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This piece of code works fine on body area:

```
<div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 30%;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it is not working when placing it inside a popover.

Here is code for the popover button:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-white" style="margin-top:-5px;margin-bottom:-7px;" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Average reviews">97.5% approval</button>
```

JS code:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
 placement : 'top',
 trigger : 'hover',
 html : true,
 content: function() {
 return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
 }
});
```

And Popover content:

```
  <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
    <div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 30%;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress" style="height: 15px;">
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 30%;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress" style="height: 15px;">
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 30%;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also, I must say that popover appears to work properly when rendering an image or styling the text (for example, strong tags are working properly), but fa-fa-icons inside it get rendered black even specifying a color, what makes me think that somehow CSS properties are being limited inside the popover element. Does anyone know why this happens, and if it can be somehow fixed? Is this approach just wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like it can be solved by applying a false value to the property "sanitize" in the JS code:

```
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement : 'top',
            trigger : 'hover',
            html : true,
            sanitize: false,
            content: function() {
              return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
            }
        });
```